# SQL Select Case Combining

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

I have two select case statements that I would like to merge together somehow. I've tried different variations of nesting, and so far I've been getting nothing but errors. I'm using SQL Server 2008 for this, and would like it to be backwards compatible to SQL 2005 if possible, as we have a second instance set up that's 2005.

What I'm doing is looking at the number of payments on an account, and trying to decide if it's weekly, biweekly, monthly, or bi-monthly.

Depending on the number of payments scheduled, depends on which date I use to calculate the days between payments. Because there isn't a true weekly, bi-weekly, etc. selection, we're using a range of days based on the amount of days between their first scheduled payment and their last scheduled payment, divided by the number of payments.

Here are the two case statements I have: The first one gives me the number of days between payments.

```
    case NoPymnts
    when 1 then 0
    when 2 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt2)/NoPymnts)
    when 3 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt3)/NoPymnts)
    when 4 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt4)/NoPymnts)
    when 5 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt5)/NoPymnts)
    when 6 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt6)/NoPymnts)
    when 7 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt7)/NoPymnts)
    when 8 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt8)/NoPymnts)
    when 9 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt9)/NoPymnts)
    when 10 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt10)/NoPymnts)
    when 11 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt11)/NoPymnts)
    when 12 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt12)/NoPymnts)
    end as DayCount
```

This one contains the logic to decide the payment frequency:

```
    case
    when DayCount = 0 then 'SinglePayment'
    when DayCount <=7 then 'Weekly'
    when DayCount >7 and DayCount <= 21 then 'Bi-Weekly'
    when DayCount >21 and Daycount <= 42 then 'Monthly'
    when DayCount > 42 then 'Bi-Monthly'
    End As Frequency
```

One option I know that works, but is large and messy is to put the second case into a sub-case statement for each of the options in the first case statement. I would really prefer to avoid this. The second option I would like to avoid is using a temp table. Though, if it is not possible to do what I am trying here, I may be forced to use one anyways.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can create user defined function for the second case statemnt and use it in the first case

Comment: As soon as you have multiple columns with identical names other than an index, you've probably got a broken data model. Consider if this model was normalized and the `1`-ness or `5`-ness was actually stored in a column and there was just one `DueDt` column. The first `CASE` statement disappears and you just have a basic select statement to pick the appropriate rows to combine.

Comment: We don't have any control over the software, it's purchased, so we're locked into the terrible database garbage they do...

Comment: Kiran: That is something I've never done before, could you give an example that I can go off of for me to start this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a user defined function for the second case as below

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetFrequencyFromDayCount 
(
    @DayCount INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Freq NVARCHAR(50)
    SELECT @Freq = case
    when @DayCount = 0 then 'SinglePayment'
    when @DayCount <=7 then 'Weekly'
    when @DayCount >7 and @DayCount <= 21 then 'Bi-Weekly'
    when @DayCount >21 and @DayCount <= 42 then 'Monthly'
    when @DayCount > 42 then 'Bi-Monthly'
    End 
    RETURN @Freq
END
GO
```

Call the function in the first case statement, something like below

```
select
  case NoPymnts
    when 1 then 0
    when 2 then GetFrequencyFromDayCount((datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt2)/NoPymnts))
    when 3 then GetFrequencyFromDayCount((datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt3)/NoPymnts))
    when 4 then GetFrequencyFromDayCount((datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt4)/NoPymnts))
    when 5 then GetFrequencyFromDayCount((datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt5)/NoPymnts))
    when 6 then GetFrequencyFromDayCount((datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt6)/NoPymnts))
    when 7 then GetFrequencyFromDayCount((datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt7)/NoPymnts))
    when 8 then GetFrequencyFromDayCount((datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt8)/NoPymnts))
    when 9 then GetFrequencyFromDayCount((datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt9)/NoPymnts))
    when 10 then GetFrequencyFromDayCount((datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt10)/NoPymnts))
    when 11 then GetFrequencyFromDayCount((datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt11)/NoPymnts))
    when 12 then GetFrequencyFromDayCount((datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt12)/NoPymnts))
    end as DayCount
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the example. I will work on this and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace value of `DayCount` in the second case with the calculation you use in the first case, as you seem to be doing the same calculation regardless of `NoOfPymts` with the exception of the single payment:

```
case
    when NoPymnts = 1 then 'SinglePayment'
    when (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt2)/NoPymnts)<=7 then 'Weekly'
    when (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt2)/NoPymnts)>7 
         and (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt2)/NoPymnts)<= 21 then 'Bi-Weekly'
    when (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt2)/NoPymnts)>21 
         and (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt2)/NoPymnts)<= 42 then 'Monthly'
    when (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt2)/NoPymnts)> 42 then 'Bi-Monthly'
    End As Frequency
```

Comment: That's my mistake. I tried to simplify the column names so they made sense to those reading this, and I didn't update the second date in the date comparison. Sorry. :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply looking for a way to find the day count first and then build on it? Then use a derived table query:

```
select
  some_column,
  other_column,
  case
    when DayCount = 0 then 'SinglePayment'
    when DayCount <=7 then 'Weekly'
    when DayCount >7 and DayCount <= 21 then 'Bi-Weekly'
    when DayCount >21 and Daycount <= 42 then 'Monthly'
    when DayCount > 42 then 'Bi-Monthly'
  End As Frequency
from
(
  select 
    some_column,
    other_column,
    case NoPymnts
      when 1 then 0
      when 2 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt2)/NoPymnts)
      when 3 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt3)/NoPymnts)
      when 4 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt4)/NoPymnts)
      when 5 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt5)/NoPymnts)
      when 6 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt6)/NoPymnts)
      when 7 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt7)/NoPymnts)
      when 8 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt8)/NoPymnts)
      when 9 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt9)/NoPymnts)
      when 10 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt10)/NoPymnts)
      when 11 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt11)/NoPymnts)
      when 12 then (datediff(d, DueDt1, DueDt12)/NoPymnts)
    end as DayCount
  from mytable
) myderivedtable;
```